# Google Dart Simple Contact form

Tags: dart

I'm trying to make a contact form in Dart. So far I can understand the server needs to include something like the following:

server

```dart
app.addRequestHandler(
  (req) => req.method == 'POST' && req.path == '/adduser',
    (req, res) {
      //process json data
    };
  }
);
```

And a form for the client:

```html
<form method="post" action="/adduser">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Add a user</legend>
    <p><label>First name</label>
    <input name="user[first_name]"/></p>

    <p><label>Email</label>
    <input name="user[email]"/></p>

    <p class="actions"><input type="submit" value="Save"/></p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

What needs to be done on the client side to get the json data to the server side?

Is json necessary to process the form or is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you want to use Dart? To submit the form using an AJAX request? Because that form can obviously be submitted as is, without the use of Dart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can submit your `form` to server directly. The content will be sent *URL-encoded* in the body of the `post` request. On server, you can decode datas with the [`query_string` package available on pub](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/query_string).

Add `query_string` to your pubspec.yaml file:

```yaml
dependencies:
  query_string: ">=1.0.0 <2.0.0"
```

Your server code can looks like :

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:query_string/query_string.dart';

main() {
  final server = new HttpServer();
  server.listen('127.0.0.1', 8081);
  server.addRequestHandler((req) => req.method.toUpperCase() == 'POST' 
      && req.path == '/adduser', (request, response) {
    readStreamAsString(request.inputStream).then((body) {
      final params = QueryString.parse("?${body}");
      print(params["user[first_name]"]);
      print(params["user[email]"]);
      response.statusCode = HttpStatus.CREATED;
      response.contentLength = 0;
      response.outputStream.close();
    });
  });
}

Future<String> readStreamAsString(InputStream stream) {
  final completer = new Completer();
  final sb = new StringBuffer();
  final sis = new StringInputStream(stream);
  sis
    ..onData = () { sb.add(sis.read()); }
    ..onClosed = () { completer.complete(sb.toString()); }
    ..onError = (e) { completer.completeException(e); };
  return completer.future;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, as always great example!