# How to create forms in dart?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

What is the best way to create forms (textfields, checkboxes, radio buttons, ...) and handle the data after the user's input?

Just use web components as dart's web ui?

- http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/
- http://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/web-ui/

**edit:** Lets imagine the following example application: I would like to create an online quiz/test.

- First the user has to register
- Data will be stored in a textfile or in a database
- User can log in and play an online quiz or do an online test.
- For that quiz/test i need to evaluate the input with the predefined correct answers

Comment: do you mean how to handle them on server side?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic see my edited question. I am interested in generating a form and also handling the data serverside.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a high-level answer to your question.

To handle data on the server side you can use the HttpServer class to start a web server. See this [article](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/io/#writing-web-servers).

To store data in a flat file you'll need to use the dart:io package to open a file and write to it. See the documentation for [File.openWrite()](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/File.html#openWrite).

To store data in a database there are packages available on pub for [mysql](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqljocky) and [postgresql](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/postgresql).

There are two different ways to implement the client side. The traditional way is to use [templating](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mustache) to generate html with the data in input elements within a form tag, and then handle the form submission in your webserver.

The modern way, that is the focus within the Dart community, is to write a single page app, which uses [HttpRequest](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/HttpRequest.html) to read data from and send data to the server (usually using [json](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_json.html)).

Comment: That is the question. Just use simple html forms and get the values server side or send the form with its values back as a json to the server.

Comment: The "best" way depends on your exact use case, and personal preference. I'd probably go with the json/httprequest route, just because that's what most other people in the community are doing. The more trodden path is often easier. It's also faster - no page refresh and you don't need to do Post-redirect-get, leading to an extra round trip or two.

Comment: I hate the 7 different roads to rome. I can imagine many developers needing some kind of quickly developed simple forms to provide user input and they will have the same question.

Comment: Serverside dart doesn't have a large mature set of libraries like node.js does. It's still early days, and the team at google are focusing on clientside at the moment. If you want to build server side code in dart you'll have to do some research and try stuff out. If you come up with a good solution post it here ;)

Answer (score 1):

On the client side, you could retrieve data from server (e.g. as JSON) and use that to build a form. This seems like a good fit for a web component as elements can be dynamically added based on received data.

The component would be bound to the model so you can [serialize the model object to JSON](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/fetchdata/) on submit and send it to server on submit or just send it as standard HTML form.

The server side of the story is less clear, there are no production quality web server libraries that I am aware of, but you could take a look at [DartExpress](https://github.com/Dartist/Express) as an example, or [Stream](http://rikulo.org/projects/stream), and there are others, more or less complete. Anyway, you would have to extract the POST payload from [HttpRequest](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/) (if sent as JSON) or use [the form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648615/google-dart-simple-contact-form) which is also accessible via [`queryParameters`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/HttpRequest.html#queryParameters) property - please note that this is `Dart:io.HttpRequest` class, not `Dart:html.HttpRequest`, and it is available only on server side.

The mentioned server frameworks simplify this part a bit.

Comment: In my case the form would always be the same. I like the idea of serializing. IMHO Dart needs one good web server library!

Comment: sure, the server side story is far behind node, at the moment. WRT form, if it is always the same, I would most likely just write it directly in the main HTML, and not use components, but it depends on complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Using Web-UI would be a good choice. The todomvc application illustrates nicely how to dynamically capture the input from a user. Processing on the server side is wide open as far as choices go. Dart does have server side capabilities, and you could use some of the existing libraries to accomplish what you want.

Another way that you can process the information server side is to comunicate with the DB directly using a REST based web service like CouchDB. Cloudant offers such a service and allows you to communicate directly to the DB from the client, providing you can overcome the Same-Origin-Policy. There are 2 ways to do this. Enable CORS on the CouchDB instance, or host your application on the server that has the DB, which is also possible with CouchDB.

Dart serverside also supports websockets, so you can easily deliver the user provided data to the server with web sockets, and then do whatever processing you like on the serverside.

One other option I can think of would be to have the information processed and saved in the local browser. You can access the local DB or local browser file system from the Dart client, and keep everything local. For statistics, you can have the client update a web service of your choice.